# display glyphicon or image when user makes payment?

Tags: php, mysql

So i have user login/registration system setup for my website and was wondering how I could display to the user that a payment has not been made and a button is displayed for them to redirect to another page to make payment. When the user makes the payment (via bitcoin) I manually change the `paid` from a 0 to a 1 in my PHPAdmin then the user will be displayed with a tick and the pay now button is removed. heres a photo of what it should look like after I have manually changed the value.

[image]

and something like this for when the account has not been paid.

[image]

and what my code looks like for that section:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove logo-account"></span>
        <h4>ACCOUNT STATUS</h4>
        <p>please click below to make a payment</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="login_main.php" role="buton">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bitcoin"></i>
          Pay Now
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: when you get back return with payment url then you will check which status has been coming. after you will place there if condition ans set glyphicon logo class path over there.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I dont see any code referring to the status of the payment in the provided code above. We're not here to write code for you. You should get the payment status form the database for the currently logged in user, and in some sort of IF-statement, either show one, or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Query your Db to check if it's a 1 or 0.

Take the following pseudo code:

```
//$paidValue from DB query

if($paidValue == 1) {
echo'
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove logo-account"></span>
        <h4>ACCOUNT STATUS</h4>
        <p>please click below to make a payment</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="login_main.php" role="buton">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bitcoin"></i>
          Pay Now
        </a>
      </div>';
} else {
 //echo alternative HTML here
}
```